# Can type be created(or template instantiated) by object known at compile time?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, metaclass

Suppose I have a template function:

```
template <typename T, T value>
auto foo(std::integral_constant<T, value>)
{
     if constexpr (value == 0)
     {
         return int{};
     }
     else
     {
         return float{};
     }
}
```

And I want to call it using a number constant:

```
foo(4);
```

Can it be implemented? If no, why?

I see that I can create `std::integral_constant` on my own, but I'm interested in the idea of creating a type from an object. In the example above, I have `4` as the object and `std::integral_constant` as the type.

Declaring some `define` which will do `if` or `switch` is not a solution - it will be a lot of code and slow.

Comment: I don't see the point of having type `T`. But otherwise, it looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I absolutely do not recommend this, but you could use a macro to achieve the syntax you're after:

```
template <auto value>
auto foo_impl()
{
     if constexpr (value == 0)
     {
         return int{};
     }
     else
     {
         return float{};
     }
}

#define foo(constant) foo_impl<constant>()


int main(){
    auto should_be_int = foo(0);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(should_be_int)>);

    auto should_be_float = foo(1);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<float, decltype(should_be_float)>);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z1rr4dPPW)

Ultimately you're better sticking to [bolov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71590088/27678) for now until [constexpr function parameters (P1045)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html) is standardized (or something similar to it).

Comment: your answer is pretty close to API what I expect.  But seems, without defines it will be possible only with http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html get approval

Comment: @Nufun That is correct. The language itself prevents function parameters from being used as template parameters elsewhere. There doesn't seem to have been any work on the linked proposal since 2019, so I wouldn't get your hopes up that it would be coming anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is the calling syntax for your function:

```
auto x = foo(std::integral_constant<int, 24>{});
// or
auto y = foo<int, 24>({});
```

---

However you don't need the `integral_constant`. You can simplify to this:

```
template <int value>
auto bar()
{
     if constexpr (value == 0)
         return int{};
     else
         return float{};
}

auto test()
{
    auto x = bar<24>();
}
```

---

But from your description even that is not what you actually want. Although is not very clear it looks like you want a type based on a value. If that is the case then you need a type alias, not a function, because functions return values and not types.

Here is the type alias version:

```
template <int Value>
struct my_type
{
    using type = float;
};


template <>
struct my_type<0>
{
    using type = int;
};

template <int Value>
using my_type_t = typename my_type<Value>::type;


using T = my_type_t<24>;
using U = my_type_t<0>;
```

Comment: your code works similiarly to `std::integral_constant`, but I want to avoid use of `<>` as argument input, at least from not in public API

Comment: @Nufun why do you want to avoid the use of `<>`? It's a integral part of the C++ language.

Comment: I posted this question because I wanted to have some type that would allow compare char arrays at compile time. You may say we can create it as `constexpr`, but the thing is that type that hold this array will address it via `this`, thus I can not use `if constexpr` for example, but I can do it if value is used as template non-type argument. Unfortunatelly, char array can be used as template non-type argument only using tricks that really complicates API. So, I wanted to have some type that would represent string, it means one type per unique string